# Create Windows 7 System Image from command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, backup, disk-image

Does anyone know the tool and the exact command that Windows 7 uses to create a system image when using the "Back up your files" -> "Create a system image" option?

I would like to add this task to a batch file that is supposed to run a full backup including OS, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-start-system-image-backup-from-the-command-line.html ?

Answer (score 6):

To run a backup from command line you need to run WBadmin
The Technet article for this is [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015.aspx)

To configure a regularly scheduled backup, you must be a member of the Administrators group. To perform all other tasks with this command, you must be a member of the Backup Operators or the Administrators group, or you must have been delegated the appropriate permissions.

Example:
Backing up your C: drive to the E: Drive, intending on a bare metal recovery, including system state with no prompts to the user.

wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:E: -include:C: -allcritical -systemstate -quiet